# Values not reactive once available in Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I'm  retrieving my data from my api using `vue-resource` which is happening correctly, the state is updated and from the console I am able to see the values I'm requesting. My problem is that when the application loads the data from the store doesn't seem to be impacting the application on load, but if for example I change between pages the information is displayed correctly. This is leading me to believe somewhere along the way I have gotten the life cycle hooks incorrect, or I have handled the state incorrectly inside vuex.

Vuex store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
  twitter: 0,
  instagram: 0,
  youtube: 0,
  twitch: 0
}

const actions = {
  LOAD_METRICS: ({commit}) => {
    Vue.http.get('http://109.74.195.166:2000/metrics').then(response => {
      let out = [{
        twitter: Number(response.body[0].twitter),
        instagram: Number(response.body[0].instagram),
        youtube: Number(response.body[0].youtube),
        twitch: Number(response.body[0].twitch)
      }]
      commit('SET_METRICS', out)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_METRICS (state, obj) {
    state.twitter = obj[0].twitter
    state.instagram = obj[0].instagram
    state.youtube = obj[0].youtube
    state.twitch = obj[0].twitch
  }
}

const getters = {}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
})
```

Here I am trying to dispatch an event to gather the needed information using a mutation.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavigationTop></NavigationTop>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <SocialBar></SocialBar>
    <CopyrightBar></CopyrightBar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    ready: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_METRICS')
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900');

  #app {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url('./assets/Images/bodyBackground.jpg');
  }
</style>
```

Then finally I am requesting the information inside of the component to be used by countup.js and also giving it to the method inside data.

```
<template>
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="container hero-content">
      <div class="row hero-back align-items-end">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" v-for="icons in socialIcons">
              <Hero-Tile
                :name="icons.name"
                :icon="icons.iconName"
                :count="icons.count"
                :numeric="icons.numeric"
              ></Hero-Tile>
              <h1>{{origin}}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="diagonal-left-lines"></div>
    <div class="home-hero-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="../../assets/Images/home-hero.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HeroTile from './Hero-Tile'
  import CountUp from 'countup.js'

  export default {
    components: {HeroTile},
    name: 'hero',
    data () {
      return {
        origin: '',
        socialIcons: [
          {
            name: 'twitter',
            iconName: 'twitter',
            count: this.$store.state.twitter,
            numeric: 26000
          },
          {
            name: 'instagram',
            iconName: 'instagram',
            count: this.$store.state.instagram,
            numeric: 35000
          },
          {
            name: 'youtube',
            iconName: 'youtube-play',
            count: this.$store.state.youtube,
            numeric: 15000
          },
          {
            name: 'twitch',
            iconName: 'twitch',
            count: this.$store.state.twitch,
            numeric: 127000
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateNumbers: function () {
        let options = {
          useEasing: true,
          useGrouping: true,
          separator: ',',
          decimal: '.',
          prefix: '',
          suffix: 'K'
        }

        function kFormatter (num) {
          return num > 999 ? (num / 1000).toFixed(1) : num
        }

        let twitter = new CountUp('twitter', 0, kFormatter(this.$store.state.twitter), 0, 3, options)
        let instagram = new CountUp('instagram', 0, kFormatter(this.$store.state.instagram), 0, 3, options)
        let youtube = new CountUp('youtube', 0, kFormatter(this.$store.state.youtube), 0, 3, options)
        let twitch = new CountUp('twitch', 0, kFormatter(this.$store.state.twitch), 0, 3, options)
        twitter.start()
        instagram.start()
        youtube.start()
        twitch.start()
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.updateNumbers()
    }
  }
</script>
```

To be clear at the moment it seems to just load '0k' so it's as if there is some form of race condition occurring causing it not to actually load the information on load-up. Though I'm not sure what the correct approach is here.

Comment: store variables are NOT reactive in `data`. you must use them in computed properties. That's why it doesn't work on page load, and does on page change. B/c by the time you change pages, the ajax has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved by what I'm going to describe as hacking as I don't actually know the exact correct answer at this time. Though what I have does work.

Points of Interest below:

Store

```
LOAD_METRICS: ({commit}, context) => {
    console.log(context)
    if (context === true) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve('loaded')
      })
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      Vue.http.get('real ip is normally here').then(response => {
        let out = {
          twitter: Number(response.body[0].twitter),
          instagram: Number(response.body[0].instagram),
          youtube: Number(response.body[0].youtube),
          twitch: Number(response.body[0].twitch),
          loaded: false
        }
        commit('SET_METRICS', out)
        resolve(out)
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    })
  }
```

In the above I am now sending an instance of the current `store.state.metrics.loaded` when the dispatch event is sent. Which is then checked to see the truthness of the current value, Because the first load should always return false we then return a promise utilizing an API call while also mutating the store so we have the values from later. Thus onwards because we mutated the loaded event to be true the next further instances shall return a value of true and a new promise will be resolved so we can make sure the `.then()` handler is present.

Component

```
created: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_METRICS', this.$store.state.metrics.loaded).then((res) => {
        if (res !== 'loaded') {
          this.updateNumbers(res)
        } else {
          this.socialIcons[0].count = this.kFormatter(this.$store.state.metrics.twitter) + 'K'
          this.socialIcons[1].count = this.kFormatter(this.$store.state.metrics.instagram) + 'K'
          this.socialIcons[2].count = this.kFormatter(this.$store.state.metrics.youtube) + 'K'
          this.socialIcons[3].count = this.kFormatter(this.$store.state.metrics.twitch) + 'K'
        }
      })
    }
```

Within our component `created` life cycle hook we then use the resulting values to identify the path to be taken when the components are created within the DOM again, this time just loading the values and allow normal data binding to update the DOM.

I believe there is a better method of approach then deliberating the logic of the state within the action setter and returning a promise that is essentially redundant other than for ensuring the `.then()` handle is present.